# UITableViewCell imageView.contentMode doesn't work in 3.0

Tags: iphone, uitableview, imageview, tablecell, contentmode

In `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, setting the `contentMode` on the imageView has no result.  If I change my build SDK to version 3.1, everything again works.

I don't get any warnings or errors when compiling on 3.0 but this code:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@head.jpg",[gametype objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]lowercaseString]];
```

seems to default to the UIViewContentModeCenter, so all of my pictures exceed the cell boundaries and encroach on neighboring cells.

Let me reiterate that if I change my target to 3.1 everything works correctly and all pictures are scaled accordingly to fit in the default imageView

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the same effect on iOS 4 SDK when using UITableViewCellStyleDefault.

For additional info see [iOS SDK UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit vs. UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182649/ios-sdk-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfit-vs-uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfill)

Comment: I posted this as an answer because I was unable to add a comment to the original post. Looks like I don't yet have enough reputation points to do so.

Comment: the image will not appear, when u used UITableViewCellStyleDefault, u have to use UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle..